Apple Watch Live Activity toggle app intent not showing
I have adopted the Apple Watch size class to customise my iPhone live activity for Apple Watch.
 .supplementalActivityFamilies([.small])
Mostly works as expected but the toggle does not display on a real device. It will display correctly on the preview canvas and will display if I change to a Button with app intent but not a Toggle. I have tried changing the toggle style too, but still not showing.
var body: some View {
        
        switch activityFamily {
        case .small:
            smartStackContent
        case .medium:
            content
        default:
            content
        }
    }
    
    var smartStackContent: some View {
        HStack{
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Text(trackName)
                    .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
                    .foregroundStyle(.primary)
                    .lineLimit(2)
                
                Text(artistName)
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundStyle(.gray)
            }
            Spacer()
            Toggle(isOn: isPlaying, intent: PlaybackIntent()) {}
                .toggleStyle(PlayWatchToggleStyle())
              
        }
        .padding(8)
    }


struct PlayWatchToggleStyle: ToggleStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        Button {
            configuration.isOn.toggle()
        } label: {
            Label {
                configuration.label
            } icon: {
                Image(systemName: configuration.isOn ? "pause.circle.fill" : "play.circle.fill")
                    .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .light, design: .default))
                    .foregroundStyle(.sonoOrange)
            }
        }
        .buttonStyle(.plain)
    }
}

If I tap the area on my watch where the toggle should be, it responds. So the toggle is actually working, but it's invisible?
